# How to read a file that is currently opened using Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm doing a project using Eclipse plugin to create an IDE. I have to read the file that is currently active for a particular string? How can I do this?

I came to know there is something called as `InputStream` plugin, but don't know what parameter to pass for it. Can anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read the file that's open in the active editor from a command handler, for example, you can do something like:

```
IEditorPart editor = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);
IFile file = editor.getAdapter(IFile.class);
```

You can then use the [resources API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#Workspace_and_Resources_API) to read the content of the file.  If you are trying to get ahold of the text that is actually in the open editor, then it matters what kind of editor you are dealing with.  Many things are based on [Text Editors](http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#Text_Editors) which have API to access the current file buffer.